# How to split a string every third space?

Tags: arrays, c, string, strtok

Say I have a string of several integers: "222 333 444 555 666 777 888 999 100"

Is it possible to use strtok or another method to split the string every nth space? So if I assigned each element to an array the result would be:

arr[0] = "222 333 444"

arr[1] = "555 666 777"

arr[2] = "888 999 100"

Edit:

I tried to do something like this, but it returned a segmentation fault:

```
for (char* c = arr[i][j]; *c; ++c)
  {
    if (strcmp(c, " ") && count < 3)
    {
      count++;
    }
    else
    {
      c = NULL;
    }
  }
```

In this instance, i'm trying to assign the value of arr[i][j] to a set of
three numbers. i is simply another array that holds different strings basically, and then j would be item # whatever.

Comment: Just scan through the string with a pointer and keep count.

Comment: @tadman could you give an example, how would I integrate that with strtok?

Comment: You don't need `strtok()`, it's trivial to iterate through a string instead. `for (char* c = str; *c; ++c)` is to scan over it, then internally `if (*c == ' ')` you have a space, and can keep count. `*c = NULL` will split the string. Basically write your own `strtok()` that splits and returns the chunk.

Comment: @tadman I tried to do something like this: for (char* c = arr[i][j]; *c; ++c)
      {
        if (strcmp(c, " ") && count < 3)
        {
          count++;
        }
        else
        {
          c = NULL;
        }
      } But it gave me a segmentation fault

Comment: It's best to edit your question to include code. It's very hard to read in a comment.

Comment: @tadman I edited so you can it better

Comment: `strcmp()` isn't the tool here, that compares the remainder of the string. What you want is `*c == ' '`, meaning "is a literal space".

Comment: @tadman I tried both strcmp and your suggestion and I still got a segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on every n<sup>th</sup> delimiter can be done in a couple of ways. `strtok()` is one, but it *modifies* the original string, so if you need to preserver the original, or if the original is a *non-mutable* string-literal, you must make a copy of the string to use with `strtok()`.

Another method that works on any string as it does not modify the original is a simple *State Loop*, where you loop over each character using a *State Variable* to keep track of whether you are in-a-word reading characters, or before/between/after the words reading whitespace (the `inword` variable below). The only new twist to add in grouping n-words is adding a counter to keep track of the number of delimiters you have encountered. (note, each delimiter can be one or any number of spaces in sequence)

You can use indexes or pointers (they are effectively equivalent for iterating over a string. With pointers, your pointer variables just holds the address of the current character as its value and you advance the pointer as you work down the string. Using indexes, the index just gives you the offset from the beginning of the string to the current character -- up to you.

Using a *start-pointer* to mark the beginning your set of words, and an *end-pointer* that you advance down the string until you find the beginning of the n<sup>th</sup> delimiter is straight forward and could be done as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtol  */
#include <string.h>     /* for memcpy  */
#include <ctype.h>      /* for isspace */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    const char *str = "222 333 444 555 666 777 888 999 100";    /* string */
    int nth = argc > 1 ? (int)strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 3,    /* nth delim to find */
        inword = 0, n = 0;;     /* flag in word 1/0 (true/false) and delim counter */
    
    for (const char *sp = str, *ep = sp;; ep++) {   /* loop with start and end pointers */
        if (!*ep || isspace(*ep)) {                 /* end of string or space? */
            if (inword) {                           /* were we in word? */
                if (++n == nth || !*ep) {           /* is this nth delim or end-of-str? */
                    size_t len = ep - sp;           /* get length of n words w/space */
                    char vla[len + 1];              /* just use VLA for temp storage */
                    memcpy (vla, sp, len);          /* copy n words to VLA */
                    vla[len] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate VLA */
                    puts (vla);                     /* output result */
                    n = inword = 0;                 /* reset counter & inword flag 0 */
                }
            }
            if (!*ep)                               /* if end of string - done */
                break;
        }
        else {  /* regular char */
            if (!inword) {                          /* if not inword */
                inword = 1;                         /* set inword true */
                sp = ep;                            /* set start-pointer to end-pointer */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** above a simple temporary VLA (*Variable Length Array*) is used to copy the group of words from the string for output. You will need to use either a 2D array of sufficient size, or an array of pointer for which you allocate storage to hold each word, in order to save each group of words for later use -- that part is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

Default split on three delims:

```
$ ./bin/find_nth_token
222 333 444
555 666 777
888 999 100
```

Split on each delim:

```
$ ./bin/find_nth_token 1
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
100
```

Split on two delims:

```
$ ./bin/find_nth_token 2
222 333
444 555
666 777
888 999
100
```

Split on 4:

```
$ ./bin/find_nth_token 4
222 333 444 555
666 777 888 999
100
```

**Using String Indexes Instead of Pointers**

If you are more comfortable using string (array) indexes instead of pointers, then you can simply rewrite the `for` loop to use indexes, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0, spos = i;; i++) {   /* loop with indexes, saving start position */
        if (!str[i] || isspace(str[i])) {           /* end of string or space? */
            if (inword) {                           /* were we in word? */
                if (++n == nth || !str[i]) {        /* is this nth delim or end-of-str? */
                    size_t len = i - spos;          /* get length of n words w/space */
                    char vla[len + 1];              /* just use VLA for temp storage */
                    memcpy (vla, &str[spos], len);  /* copy n words to VLA */
                    vla[len] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate VLA */
                    puts (vla);                     /* output result */
                    n = inword = 0;                 /* reset counter & inword flag 0 */
                }
            }
            if (!str[i])                            /* if end of string - done */
                break;
        }
        else {  /* regular char */
            if (!inword) {                          /* if not inword */
                inword = 1;                         /* set inword true */
                spos = i;                           /* set start position to current index */
            }
        }
    }
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I am struggling somewhat at converting the code you've shown with my own project. My project doesn't use argc or argv, but rather gets information form a typedef struct. I need to be able to take the specific string from an array in my structure and apply the splitting code to it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you want to store the strings. So long as you have storage of at least `len + 1` characters. You can copy `vla` to any storage you have. The `argc` and `argv` are just inputs to `main()` that I used to pass the number of tokens to consider as a group (I just did that so I could pass 1, 2, 4, etc...) The default is `3` if no argument is provided. That's all that is for. If you have a `struct`, then presumably it has a member (either array or a pointer to allocate storage for) so you can just `strcpy (your_array, vla)` to copy the groupings there.

Comment: Show me what your struct is and what form you want to store the separated strings in and I can be more specific about how to do it. In fact, if you already have storage for the separated groups, then you can replace `vla` entirely and just put your array there to copy to with `memcpy`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough approach with some basic C that can do a more patient sort of `strtok()`:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* strmultitok(char** str, char on, int group) {
  int count = 0;
  char *seq = *str;

  while (**str) {
    if (**str == ' ' && ++count == group) {
      **str = 0;
      ++*str;

      return seq;
    }

    ++*str;
  }

  if (count == group - 1) {
    return seq;
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  // Make a copy as modifying a static string results in a bus error
  char *test = strdup("222 333 444 555 666 777 888 999 100");
  char *t;

  while ((t = strmultitok(&test, ' ', 3))) {
    printf("'%s'\n" , t);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where you can see it'll print out the three chunks.

Comment: Yep, passing the address of your string is a slick way to update the pointer within the function so you can repeatedly call the function until you run out of string to process.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This example is quite simplified. Normally you'd need to retain that so you could `free()` it later.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. use strtok to build tokens with " " as the delimiter
2. loop through the tokens
3. During the loop, keep track of iterations.
4. Each iteration, concatenate it to the past iteration
5. If the nth iteration, store concatenated array in a new array
6. keep track of arrays

check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm and mess around in the live demo section to maybe give you an idea on what you want to do!

Not sure if this is the answer but Hopefully I gave you some help!